# R: Conditional variable generation in data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm writing a function that should take a data frame as an input and rescales all variables in a data frame so that they have a minimum value of 1. I've been able to do this for a vector (see code below) but have not been able to figure out how to do this for a data frame. In other words, the input to the below function is a vector and output is a vector, but I would hope to either (a) make this so an input is a dataframe and the output is a dataframe of rescale variables or (b) see how to apply the function to a data frame so that it will write over the original variables if the variable does not have a minimum of 1.

Here's my function:

```
min_to_one <- function(x) {

 # require integer or numeric vectors
 stopifnot(is.integer(x), is.numeric(x))

  # Save the minimum of x
  xmin <- min(x)

  # Find the distance between minimum and 1
  distance <- diff(c(xmin, 1))

  # If the distance != 0, add the distance if
  # x is negative and subtract if it is positive
  ifelse(xmin != 1,
         return(ifelse(xmin < 0, x + distance, x - distance)),
         return(x)
  )
}
```

I'm sure there is also a quicker way to do this also than overwrite all variables. For example, something like the below:

```
# Generate toy data frame
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), 
                 b = runif(5), 
                 d = c("a","b","c","d","e"))

# Does the vector's min == 1?
min_equals1 <- function(x) {if(is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x)) min(x) == 1}

# Apply it (this returns a list rather than a vector, would like a vector so
# one can then specify that min_to_one() is only applied to the vectors where 
# min(x) != 1
sapply(df, min_equals1)
```

Any advice?

Comment: The reason for the `list` output is that the 'd' is returning `NULL`.  You could change the function to something like `min_equals1 <- function(x)   if(is.numeric(x)|is.integer(x)) min(x) == 1 else FALSE` or probably `min_equals1 <- function(x)   (is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x)) && min(x) == 1`

Comment: On initial reading of this question I thought you might want to do something like `library(dplyr); mutate_if(df, is.numeric, funs(. - min(.) + 1))` but I think I am misunderstanding the question requirements. Could you add some example input and output data for the `min_to_one` function so we know exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: (1) Check if variable integer is numeric or integer. (2) If so, determine how far away the minimum of a the variable is from 1. (3) If the minimum is (+), subtract that distance. If the minimum is (-), add that distance. This makes the variable have a min of 1. I think this can be done by having variables that are min(x) and diff(min(x),1) in the df, using mutate_if(), then using ifelse() in the function of mutate_if() to add or subtract the diff(min(x),1) value.